# Go Redis convert HGetAll result to struct

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I'm getting data from the `redis.HGetAll` but found no clean way to convert results into my Struct.

```
var object struct {
    x int
}

result := redisClient.HGetAll(context.Background(), "the_h_key")

//TODO import the result content into the object
```

Is there any function for this spectacular case?

I'm using the `JSON` package(marshal, then UnMarshal to a struct).

Answer (score 2):

The result from Redis is a map[string]string.  For each field in the struct, get the value from the map, convert the string to the field type and assign to the field.

```
 var o object
 var err error

 o.x, err = strconv.Atoi(m["x"])
 if err != nil {
      // handle the error
 }

 ... repeat for other fields as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

If your datastructure isn't too complex, one convenient way to save data using redis is as jsons. Just `json.Marhsal()` your struct and save it as a string and then `json.Unmarshal()` that string into your struct back.

Comment: I'm using this way for now. But this way has lot of encode/decode, and Redis hash ability  is useless here.

Comment: You can build a wrapper function to avoid code repetition @AminShojaei

Comment: You are right about code itself. but the real problem is about performance. It will be better if we avoid json encode/decode, and use the pure data instead.

Comment: I understand.  I don't think `go-redis` supports that. I've noticed another package `redigo` having a `Scan` method but haven't personally used it though.

Comment: Chipping in quite later but will make an attempt to clarify things: `Scan` is a different command, it's not like the `row.Scan` from the `sql` package that scans the value and adds it to a pointer. 
Also, the initial quest of the OP is to avoid marshalling/unmarshalling a value (essentially a strict), since they're concerned hash functionality of redis is entirely unused that way.